# Create a class PrimeRandomGenerator that extends class RandomGenerator

Tags: java, class, random, primes

I have to create a class that extends `RandomGenerator` and produces a random prime number each time the user enters an interval in the main program.

I have created the constructors and the `isPrime` method but I can't figure out what to do next.

That's how far I got. I am sure there are mistakes in this, but I just can't see them.

```
public class RandomGeneratorImproved extends RandomGenerator {
    public RandomGeneratorImproved(int prime) {
        int startp=0;
        int tillp=prime-1;

    }


    public RandomGeneratorImproved(int lowp,int upperp) {
        int startp=lowp;
        int tillp=upperp;

    }


    public boolean isPrime(int startp,int tillp) {
        int prime=rgen.nextInt(startp,tillp);
        int n=0;
        if (prime<=1) {
            return false;
        } else if (prime<=3) {
            return true;
        } else if (prime%2==0 || prime%3==0){
            return false;
        }
        for (int i=5;i<(prime/i);i+=6) {
            if (prime%i==0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private RandomGenerator rgen= RandomGenerator.getInstance();
}
```

Notes:

- If the user enters only one number ( lets say: x ) then the interval will be (0,x).In other words we have to create either two methods either two constructors.
  For example:
  `public int nextPrime(int n)` or `public int nextPrime(int low,int high)`
- I am not allowed to use arrays (or other ready-made methods that make the problem way easier).
- I searched everything that involved Random Prime Numbers Generators but I couldn't find anything similar to this.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: My code won't run that's why I am posting here. It is still unfinished and I can't compile it, I can only post the part which done. Should I?

Comment: Yes, though just the relevant part for your question.

Comment: Ok, done. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: What is `RandomGenerator`? Where do you define `startp` and `tillp`?

Comment: `RandomGenerator` is a class defined in acm.jar 
also `startp` and `tillp` are the constants of the constructors.

Comment: Don't know what `acm.jar` is, it's not part of the SE libraries. Also, those variables are not declared there, they are just assigned. As I said, copy paste this class into a new project and see if it compiles. Then I will direct you on how to use it.

Comment: The library is `acm.program` and as I said this program won't compile cause it makes no sense as it is right now .Also the variables are for the constructors and i think you don't have to define them because they take the values of int numbers... Correct me if I am wrong, I am just a beginner, anyways!

Comment: "*i think you don't have to define them because they take the values of int numbers*" But the compiler doesn't know that. You have to declare them as `int`. And just copy-paste this into a new project and fix the current compilation errors. If you did, you wouldn't have had to ask me to correct you - the compiler would have done it.

Comment: In my book the constructor's variables are not defined so I don't really think that's the problem but I may try it.

Comment: Are they defined in the superclass? We can't guess here about a class we don't know.

Comment: Yeah, ok I did defined them but now it says that class RandomGenerator is not defined ...Any idea?

Comment: Since `RandomGenerator` is in an external jar don't worry about it, though keep in mind that the answers you can get will be limited. Please post the code after all the fixes. If this file is in its own project and the compiler is still complaining (except about the external jar), then it's not fixed.

Comment: Ok, i editted the post with the code as it is now. With this code the compiler says there are 3 errors and all of them concern the fact that class RandomGenerator is not defined.

Comment: Good. What does `rgen.nextInt` do?

Comment: `rgen.netInt(int low,int high)` is a method from RandomGenerator that produces a random integer that belongs in the interval given.
Note that rgen was initialized with the `.getInstance()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some advice on how to improve and use the class.

> I have to create a class that extends `RandomGenerator` and produces a random prime number each time the user enters an interval in the main program.

That tells me that the instance of your class is not associated with a range at its creation. The range is given only on the user's demand to generate a prime. As such, I would

- Create an empty constructor and to whatever initialization there is to do there.
- Add overloaded methods `public int generatePrime(int high)` and `public int generatePrime(int low, int high)`. Generally, overloaded methods with less arguments (less data) should just call the most specific method by completing the needed data (see code below).
- The method name `isPrime` suggests that it should check if a single given `int` is a prime or not. I would make it `boolean isPrime(int primeQ)`.

The only step left is to figure out what `int`s to give to `isPrime` from the specified range. Since the superclass has a method that generates a random `int` in the range, you can pass it to `isPrime` to check if it is a prime. If it is, return it, otherwise try again. Note that this is *extremely inefficient*, but with the lack of tools and info this is the simplest bridge I could find.

Here is the code:

```
public class RandomGeneratorImproved extends RandomGenerator {

    private RandomGenerator rgen;

    public RandomGeneratorImproved() {

        rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();
    }

    public int generatePrime(int prime) {

        return generatePrime(0, prime - 1);
    }

    public int generatePrime(int lowp, int upperp) {

        int prime = rgen.nextInt(lowp, upperp);
        while (!isPrime(prime))
            prime = rgen.nextInt(lowp, upperp);
        return prime;
    }

    public boolean isPrime(int prime) {

        int n = 0; // <------ this is not used
        if (prime <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (prime <= 3) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (prime % 2 == 0 || prime % 3 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 5; i < (prime / i); i += 6) {
            if (prime % i == 0) {
                return false;// "random number"+prime+"is not a prime number";
            }
        }
        return true;// "random number"+prime+"is a prime number";
    }
}
```

Note that the line `int n = 0;` gives a warning that `n` is never used. You might want to remove it.

The usage would be:

```
RandomGeneratorImproved rpg = new RandomGeneratorImproved();
int generatedPrime = rpg.generatePrime(6, 30);
int generatedPrime2 = rpg.generatePrime(30); // same as rpg.generatePrime(1, 30)
```

Comment: Thank you sir , I am really greatfull. Though, what if no prime number exists in one of these intervals? The `while` loop will never end I think...

Comment: @George.K Very true, but the specifics of the implementation are up to you and whichever tools you are allowed to use. For example, if you were able to use array, you could have stored all the integers you tried so not to repeat them, and once there are no more to try just return something like -1 to signal that there is no prime there. If you are following a book it should guide you. I just helped with the class structure and OO design ideas and conventions.

Comment: can't I do that with a for loop ? For example: `for(int i=0;i<=(upperp-lowp);i++) { 

if (!isPrime(prime) { 

prime =rgen.nextInt(lowp,upperp) 
}else { prime=-1
} return prime;`
and in the main program it would check whether prime is -1 or not.
(sry for the bad typing)

Comment: @George.K What are you looping over? `i` is not used inside the loop. And you are still generating a random `int` in the range each iteration. You are just limiting the number of iterations.

Comment: Oops, yeah sorry that definitely won't true. Never mind i will figure it out , thanks for all your help!

Comment: Maybe read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) for ideas, it's just that there isn't much more I feel that I can do with this.

Answer (score 0):

The rejection method - generating a random number in the range of interest, checking whether it satisfies the target criteria and returning it if it does else repeating the process - has the advantage that it produces perfectly unbiased results. Its disadvantage is performance (or lack thereof).

Also, trial division is just about the slowest primality test method known to Man. Depending on the use of the 'random primes', different approaches are possible. They all require the prime factors up to the square root of the upper end of the range to be available in some form, but so does Trial Division.

**Alternative 1: The Peepholes of Eratosthenes**

Given that the target range seems to be limited to small integers, the following approach is feasible: draw a random number k, sieve the range `[max(2, k - 335), k]` using a windowed Sieve of Eratosthenes and return the highest prime in that range. This works because the gaps between primes up to 4,302,407,359 are no wider than 336. Hence the tiny window ('peephole') must necessarily contain a prime.

Disadvantage: the resulting distribution of primes is uneven (biased). For example, the number 2 will only be returned if k == 2 since the next higher prime (3) is right next to it. By contrast, the number 3,842,610,773 is followed by 335 non-primes and so the probability of its being drawn is 336 times as high as that for the number 2. However, proving the bias by looking at the output isn't easy, and for automated testers it should be near impossible.

Caveat: in this context the sieving always needs to process all prime factors up to the square root of k, which involves one modulo division per prime for computing the start offset within the window. By contrast, Trial Division can reject more than 85% of all composites based on just the first dozen primes alone. Hence there's probably no situation where Peepholes actually has an advantage over Trial Division.

**Alternative 2: The Lazy Segmented Eratosthenes**

Sieving the first 2^31 numbers takes quite a bit of CPU time (about 1 CPU second in C++, lots more in Java), and a lot of that effort goes to waste unless random primes are needed in great bulk, to the tune of many millions. If only a tiny handful of random primes is needed then Trial Division is indeed the way to go but if more are desired then a lazy approach to segmented sieving can help.

Pick a segment size that does not exceed the size of the L1 cache and create a segment cache array that covers the whole target range. After drawing a random k, retrieve the reference for the corresponding segment from the cache; if it is nil, sieve the segment and store the reference in the appropriate cache slot. Then you have a segment reference in any case, so you can test the primality of k by checking the bit `(k >> 1) % segment_size` in the segment, assuming an odds-only sieve.

Segments should be packed bitmaps representing odd numbers, and `% segment_size` can be computed by masking if the segment size is a power of 2. This way you always get an answer quickly without the long wait for sieving the whole range in one go. And the efficiency goes up when you need it to (i.e. when you are drawing lots of random primes) because the cache fills itself, causing more and more primality queries to be satisfied by already-existing segments.

Unlike the Peephole method, this gives a perfectly unbiased distribution (which is kind of obvious, since it only replaces the primality test but not the actual method of drawing primes).

There's some more info in a [post on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/114023/56653) that discusses the challenge of drawing 100 random primes.

Comment: I have searched all those things you said but I couldn't think of an algorithm  to make that happen. Also, I only want an algorithm that will just run regardless of the speed (I know that's stupid but in my level all I want is to run the program). Thanks for the comment anyway!

Comment: No worry, for small numbers of queries and/or interactive speeds, Trial Division is definitely the way to go. I overlooked the 'interactive' bit in your problem description,('each time the user enters...') which is why I thought about how to get fast answers to isolated queries and even faster responses for bulk queries (e.g. Lazy Eratosthenes). IOW, getting the performance of the sieve when needed for bulk queries without having to wait for its full initialisation at program startup (which can get bloody annoying when testing). The PeepHole is more an exercise in thinking outside the box.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that last one. I will think of it and I hope i will find a way cause it is true that Trial Division makes my program really slow. You have  been really helpful, I will take your words into consideration!